# When does the (topological) cone $CA$ of an (open) subspace $A \subset X$ embed into the cone $CX$?

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let $X$ be a topological space. Let's say $X$ is Hausdorff, compact. Let $A \subset X$ be a subspace of $X$, let's say $A$ is open (though I'm not sure it's relevant).

The topological cone $CX$ of $X$ is defined as the quotient of $(X \times [0,1])/ (x,1)\sim(x',1)$. We define $CA$ similarly. In fact, the cone operator is a functor, and so the inclusion $f : A \to X$ induces a continuous map $Cf : CA \to CX$ in the obvious way.

It is clear that in our setting the map $Cf$ is injective, and thus if $A$ were compact then $Cf$ would be a topological embedding. My question relates to when $A$ is not compact, and more precisely is an open set.

> When is $Cf$ a topological embedding? Is it always a topological embedding?

Any suggestions on this would be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not, a typical counter-example is $X=[0,1]$ and $U=[0,1)$. Namely, consider the quotient maps $\pi_U\colon U\times I\rightarrow CU$ and $\pi_X\colon X\times I\rightarrow CX$. The subspace $\{(u,t)\in U\times I\vert t>u\}$ is open in $U\times I$ and contains $U\times\{1\}$, hence its image $V\subseteq CU$ under $\pi_U$ is an open set containing the cone point. If the map was an embedding, there would be an open subset $W\subseteq CX$ s.t. $W\cap CU=V$ (here, I interpret $CU$ as a sub*set* of $CX$). Then $\pi_X^{-1}(W)$ is an open subset of $I\times I$ containing $I\times\{1\}$, hence containing a strip of the form $I\times(1-\varepsilon,1]$ for some $\varepsilon>0$ by the tube lemma. This implies that $\pi_X^{-1}(W)\cap(U\times I)=\pi_U^{-1}(V)$ contains the strip $U\times(1-\varepsilon,1]$, a contradiction.

[The intuition is the tube lemma. A neighborhood of the cone point in $CX$ contains all points with $t$-coordinate sufficiently close to $1$ and this property is inherited in the subspace topology, yet no such property holds in $CU$. In fact, pushing this idea further shows that $CU$ is not even first-countable.]

However, the functor $C$ does take *closed* embeddings to closed embedding (without any additional assumptions on the spaces involved).